# SCIM 1. 1 - Change password using SCIM 1.1

Tags: passwords, scim

Is their any attribute available with SCIM 1.1 by using that we can set password in admin change mode or self change mode.
Use case 1 -  if i am trying to change users password at that time when user is going to login to managed system then managed system asked password reset.
use case 2 - if user is trying to change his own password at that time, managed system directly login with that user and it does not asked for password reset.
Can any please help me in this, i am trying to implement this by using SCIM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
Some SCIM providers may not support a password change or reset while other will.

There was a [SCIM Password Management Extension draft-hunt-scim-password-mgmt-00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hunt-scim-password-mgmt-00) draft that some SCIM providers support.

Other providers may have restrictions. [PING shows password](https://developer.pingidentity.com/en/resources/scim-1-1-developers-guide.html) as
WRITE-ONLY. The user's clear-text password. Can only be provided in a POST operation (for a create) or a PUT operation for a password change.

There is of course nothing stopping you from extending SCIM Schema to add a SCIM attribute which indicates a requirement password needs changed. You would need to of course manage the values from your Client.